# Defining the width and height in a container nested in row in flutter is leaving a space at the end of the row

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabStories extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Grid List';

    return ListView(
      children: List.generate(100, (index) {
        return Card(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(


                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                    'hi i am sfbskdbvkjsdk ksfkj sd hsdvm d dsj s bjksdvjd '),
              )
            ],
          ),
          elevation: 5,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[dont want the empty space at the end of each row. kindly help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47rQ.png)

Trying to generate a row with a container containing the image and then a text description of the same. However, getting the empty space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: List.generate(5, (index) {
            return Card(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                     width: 100,
                     height: 100,
                   ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                        'hi i am sfbskdbvkjsdk ksfkj sd hsdvm d dsj s bjksdvjd  ',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              elevation: 5,
            );
          }),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, if this answer helps, accept it and upvote it.